# How to get user count in locust event "request success"

Tags: python, locust

Locust event hook "request success" provides these parameters - request_type, name, response_time, request_length.

I am recording this value in a CSV file for further analysis. I also need user count at each request success. How can I do this?

```
class UserOne(HttpUser):
    weight = 1
    wait_time = constant(0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=50))
        self.client.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=50))

    @task
    def perform_task(self):
        logging.debug("Running user 'one'...")
        requests = Requests(self.client)
        requests.perform_task("task")

@events.request_success.add_listener
def hook_request_success(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **kwargs):
    user_count = <NEED USER COUNT HERE>
    # users = env.Environment.runner.user_count # this provides an error-AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_count'
    stat_file.write(request_type + "," + name +... + "\n")


@events.quitting.add_listener
def hook_quitting(environment, **kw):
    stat_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using a plugin found in locust docs.

```py
class Print:  # pylint: disable=R0902
    """
    Record every response (useful when debugging a single locust)
    """

    def __init__(self, env: locust.env.Environment, include_length=False, include_time=False):
        self.env = env
        env.events.request_success.add_listener(self.request_success)
        self.include_length = "length\t" if include_length else ""
        self.include_time = "time                    \t" if include_time else ""
        # print(f"\n{self.include_time}type\t{'name'.ljust(50)}\tresponse time\t{self.include_length}exception")

    # @self._events.request_success.add_listener
    def request_success(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **_kwargs):
        users = self.env.runner.user_count
        self._log_request(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, users, True, None)

    def _log_request(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length, users, success, exception):
        stat_file.write(request_type + "," + name + "," + str(response_time) + "," + str(users) + "\n")


@events.init.add_listener
def locust_init_listener(environment, **kwargs):
    Print(env=environment)
```